# Return Function Arguments from another Function

Tags: javascript, function, apply

I am trying to streamline some code but am hitting errors when I am converting something to a function. I am effectively trying to create one function that takes a single input, and then returns three things that end up as three arguments for another function.

**Note**: the final function that will take three arguments is a method titled `md.use()`

The original (working) code is as follows:

```
md.use(require('markdown-it-container'), 'warning', {

  render: function (tokens, idx) {
    var m = tokens[idx].info;
    if (tokens[idx].nesting === 1) {
      return '<aside class="warning">' + md.utils.escapeHtml(m[0]);
    } else {
      return '</aside>\n';
    }
  }
});
```

My attempt at streamlining it / making it reusable is:

```
function aside(name) {
  return [require('markdown-it-container'), name, {

    render: function (tokens, idx) {
      var m = tokens[idx].info;
      if (tokens[idx].nesting === 1) {
        return '<aside class="' + name + '">' + md.utils.escapeHtml(m[0]);
      } else {
        return '</aside>\n';
      }
    }
  }]
}

md.use.apply(null, aside('warning'));
```

This creates the following error when I try to build:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'block' of null
    at Function.container_plugin (/Users/Paul/Development/shins/node_modules/markdown-it-container/index.js:138:6)
    at MarkdownIt.use (/Users/Paul/Development/shins/node_modules/markdown-it/lib/index.js:496:10)
```

Comment: idk but maybe the apply call is messing with the context.. perhaps using a spread instead would fix it. `md.use(...aside('warning'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first attempt, the call to `use()` is direct through the `md` instance, hence invoked in the context of `md` (`this === md`).

In your second attempt, you're using `md.use.apply(null)` that's invoking `use()` without its original context (which is the `md` instance).

Try this instead:

```
md.use.apply(md, aside('warning'));
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: Spent far too long trying to get this to work, thanks for your help and clear answer!